# Optimise loading multiple tables, transforming and applying operations

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I am reading data from about 20 different tables in Pyspark. Here is the pseudo code.

```
    initialise empty list of data frame.

    For each table{

            read the table
                apply some transformation (renaming, filtering, standardise
                   fields...)
                append the transformed table to my list of data frame
           }

    Make a union from list of dataframes
    Carry out actions (such as group by sum)
    Export output
```

I am looking for a method that instead of reading the tables one by one in the loop (it's about 10 minutes per table), allows me to perform my operations in parallel and then carry out the union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use Fair Scheduler Pools . Please do through this ask , it may helpyou .

[How to read many tables from the same database and save them to their own CSV file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178294/how-to-read-many-tables-from-the-same-database-and-save-them-to-their-own-csv-fi)